# storing elements from a file into an array/matrix

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, adjacency-matrix

im trying to save elements from an input file which contains lines such as:

```
numNodes 2
numEdges 2
node 0 0.62 
node 1 0.83 
edge 0 1 -silence- 0 78 
edge 0 2 -silence- 0 38
```

I've opened the file using scanner and broke the input into lines and words, to access each individual string.

Im trying to save each double in a node line within an array containing doubles:

```
this.nodeTimes = new double[numNodes];
```

And likewise save the three words on each edge line in an adjacency matrix:

```
this.adjMatrix = new Edge[numNodes][numNodes];
```

However in my attempts I hit ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions

```
 for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String line = list.get(i);
...
    } else if (words[0].equals("node")) {
        nodeTimes[numNodes] = Double.parseDouble(words[3]); // trying to get doubles
    } else if (words[0].equals("edge")) {
            adjMatrix[Integer.parseInt(words[1])][Integer.parseInt(words[2])] = new Edge((words[3]), Integer.parseInt(words[4]), Integer.parseInt(words[5])); // trying to store edge values
```

this similarly happens if I try something like:

```
    while(openedFile.hasNextDouble()){
        nodeTimes[numNodes] = openedFile.nextDouble();
    }
```

Not quite sure how im getting hung up

Edit:

accessing with:

```
nodeTimes[Integer.parseInt(words[1])] = Double.parseDouble(words[3]);
```

and

```
adjMatrix[Integer.parseInt(words[1])][Integer.parseInt(words[2])] = new Edge((words[3]), Integer.parseInt(words[4]), Integer.parseInt(words[5]));
```

also seem to give me an exception.

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace and tell us what line in your code the stack trace is referring to. Also what is the list you are looping through?

Comment: When you create an array using `new double[10]`, the indexes will be 0 to 9. Your code has `nodeTimes = new double[numNodes]`, but then you have `nodeTimes[numNodes] = ...`, and index `numNodes` doesn't exist, only values `0` to `numNodes-1` do.

Comment: @Andreas so my problem is trying to access at numNodes, would I want to do: nodeTimes[Integer.parseInt(words[1])] = Double.parseDouble(words[3]); for accessing at the given node number? This also gives me an exception however.

Comment: @aviad on the lines nodeTimes[numNodes] = Double.parseDouble(words[3]); and adjMatrix[Integer.parseInt(words[1])][Integer.parseInt(words[2])] = new Edge((words[3]), Integer.parseInt(words[4]), Integer.parseInt(words[5]));

Comment: Since `words[1]` is `0` and `words[3]` is `-silence-`, you're doing `Double.parseDouble("-silence-")`. Of course that will throw exception. Or did you mean that `words[1]` is `2` and `words[3]` is `0` on the second `edge` line, because we just concluded that `nodeTimes[2]` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Andreas for the edge line im doing adjMatrixt(words[1])][(words[2])] and for the node lines im accessing with [word(1)]. shouldn't that go through?

Comment: No, because the last line has a value **`2`**, and your arrays only support indexes of 0 to 1.

Comment: @Andreas forgive me, I dont quite follow, how would I allow my arrays to support the full range of indexes?

Comment: What full range would that be? You only have two nodes, indexed 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code again, I see where the issue is.

You are creating an array of size numNodes with this line.

```
this.nodeTimes = new double[numNodes];
```

Then you are trying to access the index at numNodes with this line

```
nodeTimes[numNodes] = Double.parseDouble(words[3]);
```

Accessing the index at the size of the array will always give you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions`

You can only go from 0 to `numNodes - 1`

Comment: should I access the array at each value of the node, the 2nd word? nodeTimes[Integer.parseInt(words[1])] = Double.parseDouble(words[3]); would also give me an index out of bounds exception.